# Is there any way to use BiConsumers as simply as Consumers?

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

This is just a theorical question with no concrete application.

I have the following method which I will not touch. It could (if possible at all) be used as a `BiConsumer`.

```
void doSmallThing(A a, B b) {
  // do something with a and b.
}

void doBigThing(List<A> as, B b) {
  // What to do?
}
```

How can I iterate on `as` while keeping `b` constant and use `this::doSmallThing` in `doBigThing`?

Of course the following doesn't work.

```
void doBigThing(List<A> as, B b) {
  as.stream()
  .forEach(this::doSmallThing);
}
```

The following works nice and is actually what I use everyday.

```
void doBigThing(List<A> as, B b) {
  as.stream()
  .forEach(a -> doSmallThing(a, b));
}
```

The following also works well, but is a bit more tricky.

```
Consumer<A> doSmallThingWithFixedB(B b) {
  return (a) -> doSmallThing(a, b);
}

void doBigThing(List<A> as, B b) {
  as.stream()
  .forEach(doSmallThingWithFixedB(b))
}
```

But all of those solutions don't get the simplicity of the `Consumer` case. So is there anything simple that exists for `BiConsumer`?

Comment: Iterate on `A`s and keep a constant `B` for my iteration, as the last two examples show...

Comment: I clarified directly in the question. I hope that the question in itself makes more sense now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to "bind" the function argument. Unfortunately there's no built-in mechanism to do this in Java 8 (except binding the object for instance methods like `this::`). You may generalize your `doSmallThingWithFixedB` method like this:

```
public class Bind {
    public static <A, B> Consumer<A> bindLast(BiConsumer<A, B> fn, B b) {
        return a -> fn.accept(a, b);
    }

    public static <A, B> Consumer<B> bindFirst(BiConsumer<A, B> fn, A a) {
        return b -> fn.accept(a, b);
    }
}
```

And use:

```
void doBigThing(List<A> as, B b) {
  as.stream()
    .forEach(Bind.bindLast(this::doSmallThing, b));
}
```

Probably there's some third-party library which already contains such methods. However using explicit lambda seems ok for me. You should not try to express everything with method references.

Comment: Indeed, I shouldn't try to express, but I'm still unfamiliar with everything I can and cannot do with Java 8, hence this question. If there is one, what is it? There is none, and your answer is rather clear on that. Thanks!

Comment: Afaik, this is *partial function application*, not currying (so you shouldn’t name the methods “curry…” but rather “bind…”, that’s a naming which is not only more correct, but even understandable to programmers who don’t know what currying is). Currying would be a method like `<A, B> Function<A,Consumer<B>> curry(BiConsumer<A, B> fn) { return a -> b -> fn.accept(a, b); }`; with that you could bind the first arg like `curry(this::doSomething).apply(a)`…

Answer (score 1):

BiConsumers are used when iterating over Map entries for example:

```
Map<A, B> map = ...;
map.forEach(this::doSomething);
```

[`Stream.collect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) also takes BiConsumers as arguments, but it's used less often than an iteration on map entries.

Comment: Indeed, I saw the *`Map`* and *`collector`* use cases, but actually not any other.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, remember that method reference usage is not limited by JDK. Third party libs may utilize them as well. I use `BiConsumer` type in my `StreamEx` library, for example. You can write `StreamEx.of(as).mapToEntry(a -> b).forKeyValue(this::doSmallThing)`. I believe there are other libraries as well which accept `BiConsumer` type.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method `doSmallThing`to B:

```
class B {
    public void doSmallThing(A a) {
         YourClass.doSmallThing(a, this); // You may want to inline this.
    }
}
```

and call it from `doBigThing`:

```
void doBigThing(List<A> as, B b) {
    as.stream()
        .forEach(b::doSmallThing);
}
```

Comment: This is inapplicable in most cases where `B` is a `String`, a `List`, a `Map` or anything else I don't have my hand on. Also, you suppose that `doSmallThings` is static, which I never wrote it is (and it is not).

Comment: Fair enough, but you could wrap `B` in and/or move/copy the functionality to `B`. :)